# Can we see which question earned us a particular hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

For example I recently got the **I'm Batman** hat which is described as

> edit a closed question (that you did not participate in closing) that gets reopened after your edit

Is there a way to see which question that was? I understand this could be difficult to implement generally, as some of the hats have requirements that are not tied to a particular question, e.g.

**Carl Fredricksen**

> at least 5 upvotes from 5 different users in a UTC day with no downvotes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, we don't show that anywhere. In fact we don't store or even query it anywhere, all we care about is the ids of the users who deserve any particular hat.

Comment: Maybe something for Winterbash 2016 perhaps? :)